# Why is my AC smelling bad and producing no condensation water?

Tags: smell, condensation

I have a 10-year Carrier unit. It has two issues.

1. The AC smells musty when turned on. It smells even worse when I turn on the fan mode after running AC. No smell when running on heat. It's similar to the problem described here: [Why is there a musty smell from my HVAC system even after coil cleaning?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/197843/why-is-there-a-musty-smell-from-my-hvac-system-even-after-coil-cleaning)

I cleaned the evaporator coil and didn't solve the problem. But the coil looked good and clean even before cleaning. The drain pan is also clean. The blower has a bit of dust, but I guess this shouldn't cause any smells.

2. I live in Orange County in southern California. When running the AC, there's very little to zero condensation water coming out... The condensation drain line is clear and drains properly if I pour some water directly into the drain pan. The AC still blows cold ai, but there's just no condensation water.

I'm not sure these two issues are related... Can anyone share any thoughts on the possible causes and solutions?

Comment: Does it make the air cold?  If so, and there is humidity, there **must** be condensation.   And, of course, you've checked the air filter.

Comment: Condensation is a result of the delta in temperature and humidity if the humidity is low there will be a small amount of moisture collected. The issue may be in the ductwork if your system is a central air the heat and cooling use the same duct work and hot air won’t collect  moisture like cold air will yes in the ducts, a little moisture activates the spores, one way to kill it is rent or buy a large ozone generator and have it blow through the ducts (with the high level of ozone the home needs to be vacant ) ozone generators can sterilize in about 4 hours if done when out of the home effecti

Comment: 58% humidity in Irvine right now. L.A. is full of micro-climates, though.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I called a third HVAC technician to take a look at our system. This guy looks more experienced. He checked our delta T, found no issues with freon level, and said our condensation is normal. As for the musty smell from the vents, he couldn't find the reason.. Our return/supply ducts look very clean and perfectly sealed. He opened the motor/blower box and didn't see anything bad there. I showed him the picture of my evapartor coil, and he said it's in an immuculate condition and the smell couldn't be from there.

Comment: The AC guy poured some vinegar into the plumbing drain line, but no vinegar smell from the vent. I told him I could get a strong musty smell when opening the evaporator coil box, but he still insisted the smell won't be from the coil because it's very clean (well, it looks very clean, and not anything like those dirty coils in Youtube). In the end, he suggested an air scrubber or UV light. I'm going to clean the coil again using a stronger cleanser and see how it goes. Not sure if running heat for 30 minutes would kill the bacteria on the coil (I just did it). BTW: I have a central system.

Comment: Re to Ed Beal: The AC guy didn't think it's coming from the ducts. But, anyway, I'll try to do an experiment over the weekend. Use a fan to blow air from a post-coil position, and then see if there'll be any smell; then use the fan to blow air from the return air ducts and see if there'll be any smell in the coil box. This can probably tell if the smell is from the ducts or not..  I just realized my system has two zones (upstairs/downstares), so the zone dampers are probably closed unless I turn on the AC fan?

Comment: How long is the ductwork in your house?   If there are any low spots in one of the runs, it's possible that is collecting dust and condensation, thus leading to the smell. Consider hiring a duct - purging/cleaning company.

Comment: The ductwork is about 9-10 years. There aren't any spots. I'll buy a snaking camera to check the deep inside of the ductwork.

Comment: Update: I used a snaking camera to check the ductwork, but couldn't see much. But, a strong smell (the same one I got from vents) was around the evaporator coil and drain pan. I put my hands on the evaporator coil, and could feel lots of water trapped between the fins (I only ran the AC for a few minutes about 20 hours ago)... While I can't smell anything from the water, I guess it won't be fresh.. This may explain very little condensation water, and also the unfresh smell from the vents. What's the reason condensation water is collecting inside the evaporator coil? The coil looks very clean.

Comment: It looks like the evaporator coil has some (invisible) debris in it that stops the condensation water from dripping into the pan? And, the trapped condensation water also collects the dust/bacteria/mold and creates musty smells when blown out?

Comment: Also, just a wild guess: I'm using 3M filter with MPR rating of 2200. It seems to restrict lots of airflow? I read online that restricted airflow can cause evaporator freezing and hence holding condensation water on the coil instead of letting it drip down to the pan and drain..